# Crear un layout para una pantalla específica

Tags: android, layout

Saludos compañeros, un gusto saludarlos. Tengo una app con sus diferentes versiones para pantallas (small, normal, large y extraLarge), cada una con su `xml` diseñado para cada tipo, pero me encontre con un telefono `Huawei` con esta pantalla `3.5" HVGA 320x480`. Mi pregunta es:

No deberia la UI de android usar la configuración `small` para esta pantalla?

Resulta que la app cuando se ejecuta en este teléfono usa el `xml` para `normal`. Cómo puedo cambiar eso?. He intentando crear varios tipos de pantalla (create other) con múltiples configuraciones sin resultado óptimo. Alguna sugerencia? Gracias por sus comentarios.

NOta: Los tamaños en el diseño `xml` los doy en `dp` pero mi `activity_main` tiene especificaciones especiales lo que me hace crear diferentes `xml`

Comment: Intenta diseñar con layouts expansibles, relativelayout, usar dpi, no te será necesario diseñar por cada pantalla

Comment: Intenta crear un folder extra a tus _layouts_, llámalo **layout-normal-mdpi**  o bien en su caso **layout-large-land-mdpi** para _landscape_ y ahí metes todos los _xml_ que uses.

Answer (score 1):

Si pruebas con la densidad de pixeles (dp)  en vez de `match_parent`, puedes notar el mismo tamaño en distintos telefonos.
Los dp , ya sea en distintas resoluciones de pantalla tratan de tomar la misma cantidad de pixeles que en resoluciones altas, es decir, si tu situas un imageview con 30dp, ese mismo imageview va a tomar esos 30dp tanto en 3.5 pulgadas como en 6 , va a tratar de colocar el mismo espacio en los distintos dispositivos, en cambio, si usas match parent, lo que logras es hacer que en cada dispositivo se ajuste al tamaño del mismo, es decir, se ajusta al padre , puedes intentar con los dp y me avisas.

Comment: Armando, trata de agregar mas detalles a tu respuesta porque podría ser considerada como comentario... =(

Comment: no puedo agregar comentarios, me pide calificación de 50 :(

Comment: Entonces trata de ampliar tu respuesta, es buena oportunidad para obtener más reputación y ayudar a la comunidad! =)

Comment: Efectivamente uso dp para tamaños, de todas formas existen casos como el que tengo, revisando la documentación encontre que el "small" va desde 2' hasta 3.5', mientras que el normal va desde las 3' hasta las 4.5'. Es decir, que pueden existir móviles entre 3' y 3.5' que sean "small" y otros que sean "normal", este es mi caso

Answer (score 0):

La [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) define small como **al menos 426x320**, con lo que esta pantalla no entraría en esa categoría.

Puedes definir recursos específicos para esa pantalla pero deberías considerar si el esfuerzo amerita el % de dispositivos que cumplen con esa condición.

También está la posibilidad de utilizar el nuevo [Constraint layout](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0), que te permite realizar pantallas más "genéricas". Aunque el editor de android studio todavía no anda al 100% es una buena alternativa para crear pantallas más flexibles.

Comment: Vaya que será de gran ayuda el Constraint Layout y también el uso de gráficos vectoriales!

Comment: Eso era lo que yo pensaba, pero si entra segun la documentación "small" va desde 2' hasta 3.5', mientras que el normal va desde las 3' hasta las 4.5'. Es decir, que pueden existir móviles entre 3' y 3.5' que sean "small" y otros que sean "normal", este es mi caso, un movil con una pantalla pequeña que entra en "normal"

Comment: Si hablas por el grafico, eso muestra a modo ilustrativo donde podría caber un dispositivo pero hoy en día con la gran variedad de dispositivos es muy variado el concepto de 4" , ya que cuentas con distintos tamaños y resoluciones. Hay que usar las medidas o mejor aún diseñar de manera "flexible"

Answer (score 0):

**Para el caso que mencionas precisamente desde Android 3.2 se agregaron nuevos calificadores los cuales determinan un layout dependiendo de la densidad de pixeles**:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers

puedes establecer una diferencia al cargar tu layout dependiendo de la densidad de pixeles, por ejemplo:

```
# para télefonos (mas pequeños que 600dp de ancho disponible)
    res/layout/main_activity.xml
 # para 7” tablets (600dp de ancho y mayores)          
    res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   
 # Para tablets de 10”  (720dp de ancho y mayores)
    res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml
```